# How can I get PHP scripts and CGI scrips in OSX Yosemite to run with my UserID?

Tags: php, apache, cgi, osx-yosemite, userid

After much work, I was (already some time ago) able to *finally* get CGI scripts to run on OSX Yosemite, but the problem is this. Neither any of my CGI scripts nor my PHP scripts (i.e. any of those stored on my account) run as my UserID, but instead, they run as the WebServer's UserID.

Of course, as last-resort, I *do* have a solution I can fall on --- I can write a CGI wrapper that solves this (yes, my level of aptitude at programming really *is* that many degrees beyond my level of aptitude at webserver administration) --- but if there is a way to fix this problem that is built-in to the system, I would much prefer to use that instead. So if anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know.

Comment: By CGI scripts, I mean actual executable files invoked by the web-server. They can be Perl scripts with executable permissions and the obligatory "!# /usr/bin/perl" line -- or they can be _binary_ executables.

Comment: Hi Sophia. Thanks for the conversation on my answer - it is good to have an honest exchange of views about how to balance forthrightness and civility when discussing a possible solution. I have deleted it for the sake of tidiness, since I don't think anything within it was helpful to the problem at hand. I hope you find a satisfying answer to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, @halfer. Once again, I realize your intent in providing the initial answer was benevolent --- but since it did not address the problem, I am glad you deleted it so that the question no longer looks like it's been answered (thereby in the _event_ that someone _does_ have an answer, causing them to sail by the question).